# Eclipse doesn't compile classes in source/main/resources directory in maven project

Tags: eclipse, maven

I have created a maven project in eclipse using the maven2eclipse plugin.

I then convert the project to a web module  project by going to project facets in the project properties.

The problem is that when I attempt to create a class under the directory src/main/resources, none of my classes compile.  I can put any sort of junk in the classes and the compiler doesn't give me any warnings.  Also, the package I create doesn't create a "brown package" but a folder instead.

Does anyone know what I have configured wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`src/main/resources` is intended to hold... resources: properties files, images, etc. that are copied to the classes directory. Java source files must be put in `src/main/java`.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this : right click on your project > maven > update project configuration. It will configure you .classpath and .settings against your pom.xml configuration.

Answer (score -1):

The problem was that when you switch to this web module in project facets, the "exclude *.java" files is entered under java build path > source by default.  This must be removed.